# Convert iterator code to Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

converting this nested iteration is blowing my mind could someone convert this to a parallel stream?  I want to be able to check for assignments that match my criteria for each of my account team members.  I've just switched to java 8 and am struggling to wrap my head around the best way to leverage parallel streams to preform this aggregation.

```
for(Iterator<BasicDBObject> iterator = members.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    BasicDBObject member = iterator.next();

    //if the member doesn't have a valid assignment remove them.
    boolean memberContainsValidAssignment = false;

    BasicDBObject role = member.get("accountTeamRole") == null ? null : (BasicDBObject) member.get("accountTeamRole");
    if (accTeamRoleCodes != null && !accTeamRoleCodes.contains(role.get("code"))) {
        iterator.remove();
        continue;
    }

    List<BasicDBObject> assignments = member.get("assignments") == null ? new ArrayList<>() : (List) member.get("assignments");
    for (Iterator<BasicDBObject> assignIterator = assignments.iterator(); assignIterator.hasNext(); ) {
        BasicDBObject assignment = assignIterator.next();

        Date endDate = (Date) assignment.get("assignmentValidToDate");
        Date startDate = (Date) assignment.get("assignmentValidFromDate");

        if(startDate == null){//this is junk, should have never been allowed.
            LOGGER.warn("There's no start date for this assignment. {}", assignment.toString());
            assignIterator.remove();
            continue;
        }
        //1. open ended assignment, it lives on forever. 2.falls in between active date.
        else if(endDate == null ||(activeDate.after(startDate) && activeDate.before(endDate))){
            LOGGER.debug("adding an assignment. {}", assignment.toString());
            memberContainsValidAssignment = true;
            convertDatesToString(assignment);
            continue;
        }

    }
    if(!memberContainsValidAssignment){
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: A Stream won't let you remove anything from the underlying collection.

Comment: what about making a new list based on the same criteria? The problem I'm having is the ternary operations and the if statements.  Also not sure how I'd go about doing things like calling convert date..

Comment: IMO, your code looks just fine as it is. I don't think this is a task for Streams.

Comment: Thanks Tuanki, the only reason I was interested in adding streams was the paralleling of evaluating Members and their assignments.  Our document is pretty small right now but, I expect it will grow pretty fast.  The kind of crappy thing is I can't query mongo to give me the results I'm after due to the data model (I don't get to control that so...)

Comment: Since you are modifying the underlying collection, you cannot benefit from parallelism anyway unless the underlying data structure is thread-safe (which it probably isn't)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shot at converting your code to use streams. Please, check the details of the filter conditions.

```
 List<BasicDBObject> invalidAssignments = members.stream()
        .filter(member -> accTeamRoleCodes == null || 
                          member.get("accountTeamRole") == null || 
                          accTeamRoleCodes.contains(member.get("accountTeamRole").get("code"))
               )
        .flatMap(member -> member.get("assignments").stream())
        .filter(assignment -> (Date) assignment.get("assignmentValidFromDate") != null && 
                              ((Date) assignment.get("assignmentValidToDate") != null || 
                              (activeDate.after((Date)assignment.get("assignmentValidFromDate")) && 
                               activeDate.before((Date)assignment.get("assignmentValidToDate"))))
               )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To make things parallel would just be a matter of using `members.parallelStream` instead of `members.stream`.